# Why is the brightness key so often not working on Laptops?

Tags: keyboard, display, laptop, screen, brightness

I am not asking about a specific laptop but in general I have seen this on so many laptops. And when you Google "brightness key not working on Linux laptop" you see hundreds of posts.

What is it with Linux and laptop brightness keys? Is there some kind of a deeper underlying problem? Why is the brightness key so often not working for so many people? Is Linux incapable of handling laptop brightness? Why? What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laptops may have all sorts of different hardware, different UEFI including ACPI settings, etc.

Vendors sell laptops mostly with preinstalled Windows with hardware specific settings and/or drivers.

It is not a matter of Linux, but about installing an OS that was not intended to be used by a vendor.

In most cases brightness works, in some cases additional setup is needed. That's why there are many questions about this issue.

The problem is that there is no standard way to control brightness by a key that can be supported. Each vendor does uses their own way and almost never publishes the details.

Linux developers have to find out how it is done and add model specific quirks to the kernel code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it, I did not know that there was no standard way of doing it. That really sucks. I mean it is just screen brightness after all, such a simple thing that causes a problem for so many.